# Removing the right and bottom/right handles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/rYFEY/12/

Which works well, except I need to remove right and bottom-right handles, only leaving the bottom handle for resizing purposes.  At the moment, if I click on the right handle, the box changes size.

That should not happen, it should always stay 100% wide, and be resizeable in height only.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the handles-option:

```
handles:'s'
```

's' stands for 'south', which means "bottom" in `resizable()`.

The default is `'s,e,se'` which means south, east,south-east (bottom, right,bottom-right)

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable#option-handles